# How to release memory in iphone?

Tags: objective-c, memory

I have a `UITablView` with search box, when you type a text, content will show according starting character typed in serach box then when you select uitableview cell, it goes to another page, which has nearly 30 objects like, `UILabel` and `UITextView`. This is the way I constructed the page. When I select a company, I get a memory warning: "Did recieve memory warning level 1".

I verified every object, I had given release statement. Still I am getting the problem. How should I avoid the problem?

Comment: I think you need to provide an example of your code. We need the code to verify that it is ok.

Comment: What makes you think a memory warning is a problem? Is your app being terminated for using too much memory? Have you run your app in Instruments to see how much memory you use and where you use it?

Comment: Try analysing your code in Xcode - Product > Analyze - it might help highlight any issues

Answer (score 0):

For starter, launch your application with Instruments using the memory leaks template. This probably can tells you what objects are stay in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

in xcode 5 just go to **product -> analyse** ... then see the list of the memory leaks break point... **just go throw the break point** and **try to release those are not required variable and class object** ....

some bref

Or

This tool tells you what library is leaking, then you can debug your code as you deem suitable. If it is well organized, you will be able to see immediately what object is leaking and fix the problem with ease.